# select most recent rows with specific names in a row from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table like this:

```
Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4 date
----------
Rachel John Sebastian Luk 2015-07-20 18:20:13 
Stephan Luk Michele Steve 2015-06-20 18:20:13
Rachel John Sebastian Luk 2015-09-20 18:20:13
Stephan Luk Michele Steve 2015-03-20 18:20:13
Rachel John Sebastian Luk 2014-07-20 18:20:13
Stephan Luk Michele Steve 2015-03-20 18:20:13
Rachel John Sebastian Luk 2015-05-20 18:20:13
Stephan Luk Michele Steve 2015-02-20 18:20:13
```

And i have array like this: `$names = ["Luk","Steve","Ingrid"]`
I need to select for each array's name the most recent row, where name exists.

My current code is:

```
foreach ($names as $n){
    $sql = "SELECT date FROM dbtable 
    WHERE name1='".$n."' OR name2='".$n."' OR name3='".$n."' OR 
    name4='".$n."' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";

    $result = $con->query($sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $date[$n] = $row['date'];
}
```

It is working ok, but when array $names and mysql table gets big, it's getting slow. Maybe there is a way i could make less requests to database or better query?

Comment: you should normalize your structure - change the table design.

Comment: and you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: `select name, max(date) where names in (....)`. one SINGLE query that gives you what you want without a loop or having to run multiple queries.

Comment: You shouldn't be using strings in your where clause if you can avoid it. You could do the same thing by using the UserID.

Comment: Thanks, going to read about normalization. As for injection, i make sure names are alphanumeric. And thanx for this select name, max(date) where names in (....)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as one mysql query. But i am not sure that it will not require much resourses.

If table t1 has (Name1,  Name2, Name3, Name4, date1)

```
Create Temporary table t2 (Name0 text);
Insert into t2 values ('Luk'), ('Steve'), ('Ingrid');
Select t2.Name0, max(t1.date1) maxtime from t1,t2 where t2.Name0 in (t1.Name1, t1.Name2, t1.Name3, t1.Name4)  group by name0
```

result

```
Name0 maxtime
Luk   2015-09-20 18:20:13
Steve 2015-06-20 18:20:13
```